# Loading view from root of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, partial

This question is related to this question
[Loading view outside view folder with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358535/loading-view-outside-view-folder-with-codeigniter)

But the problem it is very old, and nobody looks it any more :(

This is problem i have, i have created function based on @SpYk3HH answer like this

**MY_Loader.php**

```
<?php
    class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
        public function base_view($view, $vars = array(), $get = FALSE) {
            //  ensures leading /
            if ($view[0] != '/') $view = '/' . $view;
            //  ensures extension   
            $view .= ((strpos($view, ".", strlen($view)-5) === FALSE) ? '.php' : '');
            //  replaces \'s with /'s
            $view = str_replace('\\', '/', $view);

            if (!is_file($view)) if (is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$view)) $view = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$view);

            if (is_file($view)) {
                if (!empty($vars)) extract($vars);
                ob_start();
                include($view);
                $return = ob_get_clean();
                if (!$get) echo($return);
                return $return;
            }

            return show_404($view);
        }
    }
```

In controller I have used it like this

**Welcome.php**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        // Load globals
    }

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data['lang'] = '1';
        $data['body_render']='mypages/home.php';
        $this->load->view("/layouts/view_layout", $data);
    }
```

**view_layout.php**

```
    <?php $this->load->base_view($body_render); ?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php echo $lang; ?>
```

But i got error, like i can not pass $lang to that partial inside partial?

**Message: Undefined variable: lang**

I modified all my contollers and views to very simple that somebody can understand.

Comment: Why not using Dino's answer? Its much simpler and working (I guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see in your codes, you didn't pass any variable to MY_Loader::base_view() when you are calling it

in your view_layout.php you need to pass variables you need

for example:

```
<?php $this->load->base_view($body_render, ['lang'=> $lang]); ?>
```

Comment: Ok, tried similar, but how to pass all variables from data. tried $data no luck

Comment: I actually included what you ask here in my answer in first place,but I removed it since it was not related to your question, you can ask another question for that