# CodeIgniter loading view via url or via file_get_contents

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was wondering if it's possible to load a view via a url or file_get_contents? I have a html file that sits outside my Codeigniter application in the Document Root in a folder that can be accessed in public.

I have tried

```
$body = $this->load->view('http://dev.app.com/Assets/2018/03/411aa377c0e092ce.html',$data,true);
```

and

```
$email = $this->EmailsModel->get_email_by_id($campaign->email_id);
$email_contents = file_get_contents($email['file_location']);
$body = $this->load->view($email_contents,$data,true);
```

Both give me this error Unable to load the requested file:

Answer (score 1):

You can't load a view via a string wherever it comes from and add data to it as you normally would (as a string can't be compiled as php). You can append strings via `$this->output->append_output($str)` however this will *not* allow you to pass any parameters to be replaced and you can't return it as it just sets the output.

You could use the `parser` library of CI and have your relevant variables in the "view" look like `{some_var}` and pass data to the view as you would normally do utilizing the `parse_string()` function of the `parser` library.

You also might be able to modify the `protected $_ci_view_paths` array seen in the `loader` file in `/system/core` to include the assets directory as a valid path to check for views and then just use `2018/03/411aa377c0e092ce.html` to load your view but I haven't tested this and am not sure if it would work.

Similar approach seen here: [Loading view outside view folder with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358535/loading-view-outside-view-folder-with-codeigniter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a curl request to get the html response of that file ( residing outside your application). Make a view file and display the data it received. Now load this view file and pass the response to this view file.