# Codeigniter load view from external folder/domain

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to get more information regarding this, but was not able to find something yet.

We have Competition Admin Back-ends for multiple Competition Organizers, each within their own CodeInginter folder.

All of these projects have a load of files that they share with the exact content. I was wondering if there is a way of storing these views somewhere on an external domain/folder outside of their CodeIgniter folder, so that I would only need to update and upload one single file instead of doing so for each project.

I do believe that this will be a security risk, so I am not sure if it is even possible, but would make my life a lot easier.

The only way that I could find to do something similar was to use PHP's `file_get_contents` and echo that to act like the view file

```
echo file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/statement");
```

But with this I would have to create a central project to handle these "shared" functions, and not just store the view somewhere.

I guess that this will still work, but was wondering if there could have been another way to do so.

Hope that somebody can shed some light on this.

Thanx in advance

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358535/loading-view-outside-view-folder-with-codeigniter

Comment: so if i understand this correctly everything is on the same server?

Comment: @Alex, yes, same server, but different domains

Comment: @Vickel, not quite, this requires the the files to still be in the same project, I want to access files from outside the codeigniter folders

Comment: Not quite. As long as the path is valid you should be able to access it from outside the ci folders. That's why I was asking if it was the same domain ;).

Comment: Perfect, I will have a look at this and further test it over the weekend and get back to you!